# How do I rank only specific rows within a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has the percent of people who engaged in a behavior, as well as the index to the general population.  I'd like to rank these behaviors by index...  *but* I want to exclude very low incidence behaviors from this ranking.

Easy to do if I just limited the entire dataframe to exclude these behaviors, but here's the catch--I still want to include them in my df; I just don't want to include them in the ranking.

My dataframe started out like this, with group as the index:

```
GROUP     BEHAVIOR  SUBBEHAVIOR  PERCENT  INDEX
GROUP1    behavior1 foo          0.521    123
GROUP1    behavior2 bar          0.013    213
GROUP1    behavior2 fuzz         1.034    103
GROUP1    behavior3 foobar       0.750    131
GROUP2    behavior1 foo          1.521    101
GROUP2    behavior2 bar          0.913    91
GROUP2    behavior2 fuzz         0.034    301
GROUP2    behavior3 foobar       0.950    87
```

But I don't want, say, that second row with 0.013 ranked.  I want instead this:

```
GROUP     BEHAVIOR  SUBBEHAVIOR  PERCENT  INDEX  RANK
GROUP1    behavior1 foo          0.521    123    2
GROUP1    behavior2 bar          0.013    213    NaN
GROUP1    behavior2 fuzz         1.034    103    3
GROUP1    behavior3 foobar       0.750    131    1
GROUP2    behavior1 foo          1.521    101    1
GROUP2    behavior2 bar          0.913    91     2
GROUP2    behavior2 fuzz         0.034    301    NaN
GROUP2    behavior3 foobar       0.950    87     3
```

I achieved the above by doing this:

```
filtered = df[fd.loc[:,'PERCENT']>0.05].copy()
filtered['RANK'] = filtered.groupby(level=0).rank(ascending=False)['INDEX']
final = df.merge(filtered, on=df.columns.tolist(), how='left')
```

(I have far more columns that make subbehavior truly unique, hence why I've passed all of df's columns.)

It works, but it feels like a very hamfisted approach, and I'm wondering if there is a better, more elegant way.  Is there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Two approaches

**Using `df.where`**:

Since NA groups are automatically excluded in `groupby` ([see here in docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#na-values-in-groupby)), and the default NA handling for [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) is to just leave them as is, you can use [`df.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) for your filter and proceed directly.

```
df['RANK'] = (df.where(df.PERCENT > .05)
                 .groupby('GROUP')
                 .rank(ascending=False)
                 .INDEX)
```

```
>>> df

         BEHAVIOR  INDEX  PERCENT SUBBEHAVIOR  RANK
GROUP                                              
GROUP1  behavior1    123    0.521         foo   2.0
GROUP1  behavior2    213    0.013         bar   NaN
GROUP1  behavior2    103    1.034        fuzz   3.0
GROUP1  behavior3    131    0.750      foobar   1.0
GROUP2  behavior1    101    1.521         foo   1.0
GROUP2  behavior2     91    0.913         bar   2.0
GROUP2  behavior2    301    0.034        fuzz   NaN
GROUP2  behavior3     87    0.950      foobar   3.0
```

**Straightforward solution**:

Alternatively, just reset the index on your DataFrame first so that you have an identifier to align the index with.

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df['RANK'] = (df.query('PERCENT > .05')  # or using a mask ofc
                .groupby('GROUP')
                .rank(ascending=False)
                .INDEX)
```

The `query` can be replaced by a boolean indexing like `df[df.PERCENT > .05]` of course.

So then

```
>>> df.set_index('GROUP')

         BEHAVIOR SUBBEHAVIOR  PERCENT  INDEX  RANK
GROUP                                              
GROUP1  behavior1         foo    0.521    123   2.0
GROUP1  behavior2         bar    0.013    213   NaN
GROUP1  behavior2        fuzz    1.034    103   3.0
GROUP1  behavior3      foobar    0.750    131   1.0
GROUP2  behavior1         foo    1.521    101   1.0
GROUP2  behavior2         bar    0.913     91   2.0
GROUP2  behavior2        fuzz    0.034    301   NaN
GROUP2  behavior3      foobar    0.950     87   3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.join(df.loc[df['PERCENT']>0.05].groupby('GROUP')['INDEX'].rank(ascending=False).rename('RANK'))
```

Can likely also use .map() + .insert() or .update() if you create a blank column before running the calculations.

Comment: i didn't use group as the index;)

Comment: .groupby('GROUP') i reset the index before this. i just didn't include that in the code. my mistake.